# How to eliminate crash when my "textfield.text" is equal to nill, or it has an invalid character?

Tags: swift

I'm making a very simple app for a school project. The problem is that when I dont enter anything on the textfield or I enter a character that hasnt a number value, my app crashes. The app consist in showing your corporal mass índex and body fat porcentaje. Thanks for your time!

```
@IBOutlet var textoIMC: UILabel!

@IBAction func btnIMC(_ sender: UIButton) {

    decirIMC()

}

@IBOutlet var textoPGC: UILabel!

@IBAction func btnPGC(_ sender: UIButton) {

    calcularPGC()

}
@IBOutlet var textoResumen: UILabel!

@IBAction func btnResumen(_ sender: UIButton) {
calcularPesoIdeal()

}
@IBOutlet var textoNombre: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var peso: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var estatura: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var edad: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var genero: UISegmentedControl!


@IBOutlet var textoError: UILabel!


var pesoNum = 0.0
var estaturaNum = 0.0
var edadNum = 0.0
var generoNum = 1.0
var imc = 0.0
var PGC = 0.0
var pesoIdealNum = 0.0



func pesoEstatura() {


    pesoNum = Double(peso.text!)!

    estaturaNum = Double(estatura.text!)!


}

func calcularIMC() {

    imc = (pesoNum)/(estaturaNum*estaturaNum)

}

func decirIMC() {

    pesoEstatura()
    calcularIMC()
    textoIMC.text = "\(imc)"

}

func calcularPGC() {

    pesoEstatura()
    calcularIMC()

    edadNum = Double(edad.text!)!

    PGC = (1.20*imc)+(0.23*edadNum)-(10.8*generoNum)-5.4

    textoPGC.text = "\(PGC)"


}

@IBAction func genero(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

    generoNum = 0.0

    }else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        generoNum = 1.0

    }


    }
func calcularPesoIdeal() {

    pesoEstatura()


    if generoNum == 0 {

        pesoIdealNum = (estaturaNum*100-100)-(estaturaNum*100-150)/2

         textoResumen.text = "Estimado \(textoNombre.text!), \nsu peso ideal seria de \(pesoIdealNum) Kg."


    }else if generoNum == 1 {

        pesoIdealNum = (estaturaNum*100-100)-(estaturaNum*100-150)/4

        textoResumen.text = "Estimado \(textoNombre.text!), \nsu peso ideal seria de \(pesoIdealNum) Kg."

    }

}

}
```

Comment: As a courtesy to readers of your question: Format the code properly. Remove excessive empty lines. Remove unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
func calcularPGC() {

    pesoEstatura()
    calcularIMC()

    if let edadText = edad.text, let edadNum = Double(edadText) {
        PGC = (1.20*imc)+(0.23*edadNum)-(10.8*generoNum)-5.4
        textoPGC.text = "\(PGC)"
    } else {
        // prompt the user to enter a numeric value
    }
}
```

The line `if let edadText = edad.text, edadNum = Double(edadText)` checks for `nil` and if the value is numeric.

Comment: Thanks! I would try it